# UITableView loading times with Swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

Currently UITableView loads information without any action on the cells, but I would like to have the cells load quickly without the need to swipe the table lower as if you were scrolling. Has anyone else had this load time issue with a UITablieViewController or UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have, and for me it was because the UITableView was being handled on a back thread. The symptoms where that it would take a few seconds to segue to a touched cell or I could touch it a second time to force it to load.

If that's the case for you, sending it to the main thread with the following should help.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // Place your code here
})
```

Comment: This is what I have, it still takes a swipe or a long wait     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {cell.textLabel!.text = redditEntry ["time"] as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = redditEntry["date"] as? String}

Comment: Setting the label with the dispatch will not do much, I believe it's the cell itself or the tableview that is the blockage here.. So maybe try a reload on the tableview but send it to the dispatch like so:             `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.yourTableOutletNameHere.reloadData()
            })`

Comment: Also, more of the code would help narrow down the issue.

Comment: this solved it thank you so much! I would vote you up but my credit is not high enough!!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Loading cells "on the fly" is a standard behavior, and it really should be fast enough. At least, it's not what causes drops in performance.

The problem, I believe, is that you probably load data for a particular cell right in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (I'm not familiar with Swift, but methods should be the same, more or less).

You should  prepare the data beforehand (independent of calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), and then just set this preloaded data to your cell.

Comment: @JamesShelton, It's best to include this code into the question, I suppose :) It's very hard to read as a comment.